# Explore every node in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am given a connected graph with N nodes (numbered from 1..N) and M bidirectional edges consisting in a couple (A,B). Edges are unweighted.

I have K people starting at node 1 and I want to explore every node of the graph. I takes one unit of time to a person to travel from one node to one of its neighbor.

How long will it take to explore every node? I am searching for an efficient algorithm to compute the minimum traversal time, but I am afraid it is an NP-complete problem. (The constraints on the number of edges and number of people are small though).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose K were 1. Then the minimisation problem reduces to finding a minimum length path that touches every node at least once.

If we construct a new weighted graph G' with the same nodes and with edges between every two nodes whose weight is the minimum distance between those nodes in the original graph, then the minimum length path through all the nodes in G is the minimum length Hamiltonian path through G', the travelling salesperson problem, which is well-known to be NP-complete.

So for at least one value of K, the problem is NP-complete. However, for large values of K (say, ≥ N), we can produce a minimum solution in much less time, since we can just construt the minimum spanning tree and find the distance of the furthest element. I doubt whether there is any such simplified solution for small values of K, but I'd definitely use the MST as a heuristic for finding a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like BFS.

You can view the graph like a tree, where the starting node is the root. From this perspective, the answer would be the deepest leaf(farthest away from the root) if the number of leafs <= the number of people, with the answer being the depth of that leaf.
This is correct because if each person visits every leaf, then in the process of doing so visits all the nodes are visited.

However, if there are still nodes left unvisited after every person visits a leaf, then you have add to the answer the max time it takes(or distance) for the closest person to visit the unvisited node.

This is not the complete answer, however. It's more complicated than that.

If you have the following image:

[image]
You wouldn't want to blindly bfs. You would want to visit the nodes in order from least deep to deepest, as that way you don't have to go down and up the path again. For example, 0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 3 -> 0 -> 4 is more efficient than 0 -> 4 -> 0 -> 3 -> 0 -> 2 -> 0 -> 1. The reason this is correct is because you can only save time on your last traversal, so you want to make that one the longest.

Furthermore, perhaps getting a person from a different branch to visit to unvisited node may be more efficient(to help the person from the current branch), so you want to assign unvisited nodes to the people of the surrounding branches if the time it takes for that person to get to 0 is less than the time it takes for the person(s) in the current branch to visit all the nodes in this branch. If one person from a branch can be assigned to multiple other branches, you want to take the branch that has the greatest number of unvisited nodes. This "helper" person(s) is also why you want to visit the nodes from least deep to deepest in order instead of just visiting the deepest node last.

All that might sound confusing, but the key is BFS. That's the solution to your problem. It's basically BFS with modifications.

As to implementation, you can use recursions(or stacks), which are usually used for tree traversals. And note that for the case that unvisited nodes > num of people, you don't have to simulate the traveling to the remaining unvisited nodes.